# Provide support for embedding feature

Tags: nodes

I am wondering how can I provide support for embedding feature. Actually in my application when user creates article/content, I need to take option from user that if his content can be embedded via embed code to some other web sites. For that he selects yes, then, system should display embed code in the article page, by using which, other people can embed this article.

Please suggest is their any module in drupal that helps me to achieve this or some tutorial helping me to achieve this will also be useful.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Embed What and which Drupal version ?

Answer (score 0):

For D6 there is [Embed widgets](http://drupal.org/project/embed_widgets)

> Embed widgets allows content such as pages, blocks, views, and nodes
>   from your Drupal site to be embedded in external sites (including
>   non-Drupal ones).

If its D7 there is [Embeddables](http://drupal.org/project/embeddable)

> Embeddable provide a method for embed thingies in content.It is a
>   pluggable system that currently allows the embedding of nodes and
>   blocks.

[Found 136 results containing the words: Embed on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/search/site/Embed?page=1&f%5B0%5D=drupal_core:103&f%5B1%5D=bs_project_sandbox:0&f%5B2%5D=ss_meta_type%3amodule)

Comment: @NikhilM, I think OP is looking for embeddable codes (nodes) of the drupal site to put into other non-drupal sites. The Embeddables module is probably for embedding of nodes/blocks in the same site.